# Отправка сообщений в конкретной ситуации! Telegram bot on Python!

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

В общем мне нужно чтобы бот в конкретной ситуации отвечал:
Например я пишу /setting
Он выдает сообщение с двумя выборами ответа
и сделать так чтобы пользователь выбрал ответ и ему бот-написал ответ. Но условия чтобы можно было получить ответ после команды /setting.Нужен так скзать многоуровневый список,  с ответом на каждый элемент из списка. Библиотека constant фаил с токеном для бота

```
import telebot
import Constant

bot = telebot.TeleBot(Constant.token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start','help','setting','info'])
def commmand(message):
    if message.text == '/start':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Хаюшки я пончикбот! Я ЛЮБЛЮ ПОНЧИКИ!!! А ты?")
    elif message.text == '/help':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Тебе нужна помощь? Я могу спросить 'Как дела?' ")
    elif message.text == '/setting':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Охх, настройки зачем ты в них залез??\n 1.Отправить жалобу!\n 2.Информация о разработчиках /info")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def hadle_text(message):
    if message.text == "g":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Наша почта ponchikbot228@gmail.com")
    elif message.text == "б":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "в")


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Команды можно отлавливать по отдельности:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['settings'])
def settings(message):
    ...
```

Для того, чтобы следующее сообщение отправилось на обработку в другую функцию, необходимо воспользоваться методом класса `Telebot` `bot.register_next_step_handler_by_chat_id(message.chat.id, name_of_function)`.
Пример кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['settings'])
def settings(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'You choosed settings')

    #Перенаправка следующего сообщения
    bot.register_next_step_handler_by_chat_id(message.chat.id, settings)

def settings(message):

    #Получаем текст сообщения
    text = message.text

    #Необходимые развлетления
    if text == ...

    else: ...
```

Comment: Спасибо, я всю голову сломал, благодарю вас за этот ответ!!

Comment: Можете скинуть ссылку на документацию или откуда вы это вычитали?

Comment: @АлексейШевцов Вся документация здесь: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api. Однако метод, описанный выше, там не встречается. Про него узнал из открытого кода одного бота.

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/telebot/__init__.py
Порылся в документации на github и нашёл методы в коде самом к каждому есть описание, но иногда описания не достаточно.
Спасибо за ответ.